# Prove that if $B\subseteq A$, then $A\backslash (A\backslash B) = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I tried this problem and I just wanted to make sure I did it right. Here it is:

Proof:

Given: $B \subseteq A$

I.) Let $x\in A\backslash(A\backslash B)$.

It follows that $x\in A$ AND $x\notin A\backslash B$, but $x\notin A\backslash B$ is logically equivalent to $x\notin A$ OR $x\in B$.

By the distributive law for logic that gives ($x\in A$ AND $x\notin A$) OR ($x\in A$ AND $x\in B$), which is just False OR ($x\in A$ AND $x\in B$).

That leaves $x\in A$ AND $x\in B$ which implies that $x\in B$, and thus $A\backslash(A\backslash B) \subseteq B.$

II.) Let $x\in B$.

Then its clear that $x\in A$ (because $B \subseteq A$) and $x\notin A\backslash B$ (because $x\in B$). However that's the same thing as saying that $x\in A\backslash(A\backslash B)$, so $B\subseteq A\backslash(A\backslash B)$.

Therefore $A\backslash (A\backslash B) = B$ if $B\subseteq A$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct.

Comment: Looks good! One note: the bulk of the first half of your proof is actually a proof of the general identity $A\setminus(A\setminus B) = A\cap B$ (under no special assumptions on $A$ and $B$). With this identity, the question becomes "prove that if $B\subseteq A$ then $A\cap B=B$ which is pretty simple. Nothing wrong with your approach, but just pointing out a possible way to streamline it.

Comment: As said before, your approach is correct. Another way of writing it would be to notice that because $B \subset A$, then $A$ is the disjoint union of $B$ and $A \setminus B$, and so the result directly follows.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks ok, but it can be much simpler if you just usebasic properties
$$
A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap \overline{(A \cap \overline B)}=A\cap (\overline A \cup B) = (A \cap \overline A)\cup (A \cap B)=A \cap B = B
$$

Comment: In the spirit of an open community for discussing and sharing, I would expect a downvote (totally legitime) to come along with a comment that could improve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

let $$A=B\cup C$$ such that $B$ and $C$ are disjoint. Then, $$A-(A-B)=A-C=(B\cup C)-C=B\cup C-C=B$$ (Because $B$ and $C$ are disjoint)